# Using subquery in insert statement(Oracle Forms Builder)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, oracleforms

I'm new to database and form builder .

I'm getting:

> Error 103 at line 10, column 2
> Encountered the symbol "SELECT"...

Whats the correct syntax for that please?

```
INSERT INTO vehicle (
                     vehicleid, reg_no, year, fuel, 
                     engine_capacity, transmission, seat_capacity, rice_per_day, 
                     modelid, policy_id, type_name, color
                    )
VALUES (:vehicle_block.id, 
        :vehicle_block.reg_no, 
        :vehicle_block.year,
        :vehicle_block.fuel, 
        :vehicle_block.cc, 
        :vehicle_block.transm,
        :vehicle_block.seat, 
        :vehicle_block.price_p_day,
        (SELECT modelid
           FROM model m 
          WHERE m.make = :vehicle_block.make
            AND m.mode_name = :vehicle_block.model),
        :vehicle_block.policy, 
        :vehicle_block.type,
        :vehicle_block.color);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Current syntax is wrong. You can rearrange as `INSERT INTO ....
SELECT :VEHICLE_BLOCK.ID,
       :VEHICLE_BLOCK.REG_NO,
       :VEHICLE_BLOCK.YEAR,
       :VEHICLE_BLOCK.FUEL,
       :VEHICLE_BLOCK.CC,
       :VEHICLE_BLOCK.TRANSM,
       :VEHICLE_BLOCK.SEAT,
       :VEHICLE_BLOCK.PRICE_P_DAY,
        MODELID,
       :VEHICLE_BLOCK.POLICY,
       :VEHICLE_BLOCK.TYPE,
       :VEHICLE_BLOCK.COLOR
  FROM model M
 WHERE m.make = :VEHICLE_BLOCK.MAKE
   AND m.model_name = :VEHICLE_BLOCK.MODEL` if sure that `make` and `model_name` combination always returns single row.

Comment: Why did you post that as a **comment**, @Barbaros? As of actual comment you wrote, it doesn't really matter whether MAKE and MODEL_NAME return a single row. If not, that INSERT statement will insert multiple rows - it won't fail (unless some constraint is violated, that is).

Comment: Yes, you're right @Littlefoot I've just missed the part that returning multiple rows wouldn't corrupt the logic after arrangement.

Comment: There seems nothing wrong with the statement. I have never used objects like :vehicle_block for bind variables, though, except for PL/SQL where I don't precede them with a colon. But if your environment allows that, I see no flaw in the statement. Here is a fiddle where I placed the insert statment within a PL/SQL block and there is no error: https://dbfiddle.uk/PFGW2dNN

Comment: @Thorsten, it is about Oracle **Forms**. `:vehicle_block.id` isn't a bind variable. VEHICLE_BLOCK represents *block name* (region in Apex), while ID represents field (item in Apex) that belongs to that block. Colon in front of it is part of Forms' syntax (something like :P1_ID in Apex).

Comment: @Littlefoot  Your last comment made this a bit confusing.  Why are you referring to Apex?  If your issue is with Forms and not at all Apex, I would suggest trying a similar call in Sql+ or SqlDeveloper in order to validate the syntax.  In those tools you will need to use real values rather than binds, but at least you can verify the syntax.  

Also, it would be helpful to always include product versions because newer versions of software often can do things older versions cannot.

Comment: @MichaelJF, I was replying to Thorsten (as you can see). As I know that Thorsten uses Apex (Oracle Application Express), I was trying to *illustrate* what certain Forms objects represent in Apex because (seeing his comment) it is clear that he doesn't know Forms; if he did, he wouldn't ask what e.g. `:vehicle_block.id` represents.